# Полю нигде не присваивается значение, поэтому оно всегда будет иметь значение по умолчанию null

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сижу уже около недели перерыл весь инет. С С# не на ты, поэтому не знаю что  делать.
В третьей строчке значение в переменную health не присваивается поэтому оно по умолчанию будет null и если оно null, то у персонажа не отнимается здоровье. Если убрать проверку, то Unity пишет (NullReferenceException).

```
public class CollisionCollider : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int damage;
    [SerializeField] private Animator animator;
    private HealthPoint health;
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        HealthPoint health = col.gameObject.GetComponent<HealthPoint>();
        if (health != null)
            animator.SetTrigger("CollisionDamage");
    }
    public void SetDamage()
    { 
        if (health != null)
            health.TakeDamage(damage);
    }
}
```

HealthPoint скрипт откуда берётся метод TakeDamage().

```
public class HealthPoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int health = 100;
    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        health -= damage;
        if (health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить данную проблему.

Comment: Непонятно, что ты хочешь. Ну присвой дефолтное значение здоровью... в чём проблема?

Comment: Тебя напрягает проверка на null или что?

Comment: Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "int" в "HealthPoint".

Comment: А зачем это преобразовывать? Становится ещё более не ясно

Comment: VS пишет такое предупреждения, когда присваиваю значение для health.

Comment: Ничего не ясно... в строчке `HealthPoint health = col.gameObject.GetComponent<HealthPoint>();`  никакого преобразования int нет  при всём желании... в строке `health -= damage;`  тоже ..... а вот если написать например `health = 5` сразу под строкой с взятием компонента  - то да, такого не может быть.... так что что-то тут не то. Ты что-то не договариваешь

Comment: VS ругается на строку `private HealthPoint health;` то что она всегда null. Если я её не объявлю, то в методе _SetDamage()_, _health_ не будет существовать в контексте. Получается мне нужно присвоить значение в `private HealthPoint health;`, но оно туда не присваивается.

Comment: В методе Awake или Start можно сделать все необходимые инициализации компонента, в т.ч. присвоить дефолтные значения или найти компоненты и впихнуть в нужные поля.

Comment: "но оно туда не присваивается." --- тебе оно вроде не нужно... ты же при столкновении производишь поиск компонента

Comment: Да. При столкновении производится поиск компонента. Анимация укуса волком игрока проигрывается. Далее в аниматоре на нужный кадр анимации я поставил событие, чтобы вызывался метод SetDamage() и у игрока снималось здоровье. Но строка `health.TakeDamage(damage);` в методе SetDamage() не отрабатывает, потому что health = null. А VS ругается на строку `private HealthPoint health;`, что к нему не присвоено значение, поэтому оно всегда будет null.

Comment: Теперь более менее понятно... Тогда тебе надо либо в методе коллизии просто писать вот так `health = col.gameObject.GetComponent<HealthPoint>();`  или, как я уже писал, в методе `Start` инициализировать заранее свойство аналогичной конструкцией и тогда уже в других местах эта строка уже не нужна

Comment: Мне нужно научиться правильно доносить свой вопрос. Всё заработало, спасибо Вам огромное! В методе коллизии сделал так `health = col.gameObject.GetComponent<HealthPoint>();`. Только я не совсем понял, почему теперь работает. Можете вкратце описать?

Comment: Написал в ответе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если писать так

```
HealthPoint health = col.gameObject.GetComponent<HealthPoint>();
```

то внутри метода объявляется внутренняя переменная `health` с типом `HealthPoint`. Она никак не связана с одноимённой переменной, которая объявлена как свойство класса, т.к. слово `HealthPoint` перед этой переменной говорит нам об объявлении новой переменной. А вот если опустить это слово `HealthPoint`, то парсер будет понимать, что значит идентификатор уже где-то объявлен и попытается найти где-то ещё, т.е. в свойстве класса.

Поэтому надо быть с этим внимательнее. Может быть бесконечное количество переменных `health` хоть в каждом из методов. Но если нужно обращаться к свойству класса - то тип перед переменной писать уже не нужно (кроме как в объявлении в самом свойстве класса конечно же).

---

P.S. Чтобы постоянно не дёргать компоненты, то можно один раз инициализировать его в методе `Start` и уже потом пользоваться. И проверки на null уже не нужны. Т.е.

```
public class CollisionCollider : MonoBehaviour {
    public int damage;
    [SerializeField] private Animator animator;
    private HealthPoint health;

    public void Start() {
        health = col.gameObject.GetComponent<HealthPoint>();
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) {        
        animator.SetTrigger("CollisionDamage");
    }

    public void SetDamage() { 
        health.TakeDamage(damage);
    }
}
```

Comment: У него параметр col только в OnCollisionEnter2D доступен, в Start это не вынести.